# git pull upstream's upstream before pulling upstream

Tags: git

If I make a new local branch A, and set the upstream to the local master:

```
git checkout -b A
git branch A --set-upstream-to master
```

and make another local branch B, and set the upstream to A:

```
git checkout -b B
git branch B --set-upstream-to A
```

and commit some changes to A and some changes to B.
I'm now on branch B and I want to pull the remote changes to master, and pull the changes from A to B so I do.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout A
git pull
git checkout B
git pull
```

This is quite cumbersome, particularly if there are many stacked branches.

**Is there a nice way to "recursively pull the upstream branches"?**

Comment: Just do `git merge <branch to "pull" from>`. Anyways, you can create scripts for this kind of stuff.

Comment: but the end result I want is for 1. master to include changes from the remote. 2. A to include the committed changes on A and the changes from the remote. 3. B to have all of the changes.

Comment: Do you want to merge all branches into master or the other way round? Just make a script that executes that commands one after another.